# Locating Existing APP ID for Adaptive Payments in PayPal Business Account

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, applicationid

I'm reaching out for some assistance regarding my PayPal business account. Long back, I  have generated an APP ID to use with the PayPal Adaptive Payments API for a project. However, I currently do not have access to this APP ID and am unsure where to locate it within my PayPal business account.

I've navigated through various sections of my account dashboard, but haven't been successful in finding where APP IDs are listed or how to retrieve the specific APP ID associated with my account.

Could anyone provide guidance on:

1. Where in the PayPal business account I can find my previously generated APP ID for the Adaptive Payments API?
2. Are there any specific steps I need to follow or account sections I should check to locate this APP ID?

Can you please provide me the suggestions on how to get the APP ID? I'm hoping to resolve this as smoothly as possible and continue with my project development

Thank you very much for your time and support.

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive payments was deprecated a long time ago (Dec of 2019 IIRC) and can no longer be used for new integrations. PayPal will not generate nor provide APP IDs, all legacy adaptive integrations should move to one of PayPal's currently supported solutions, for example [standard checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/).